# How to get thumbnail image of m3u8 video url in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, http-live-streaming

I trying to get thumbnail of first frame from m3u8 video url. here is the code i tried so far:

```
func getThumbnailFrom(path: URL) -> UIImage? {


    let asset: AVAsset = AVAsset(url: path)
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    do {
        let thumbnailImage = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(1, 60) , actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(cgImage: thumbnailImage)
    } catch let error {
        print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return nil

}
```

And in collection view cellForItem

```
  cell.locationImage.image = self.getThumbnailFrom(path: URL(string: self.model[indexPath.row].cameraImage)!)
```

Here is the m3u8 video url :  http://dev.stream.polsecled.com:1935/polsec-uai/prodabel_2.stream/playlist.m3u8

image is not shown in collection view? How to get first of frame thumbnail image using m3u8 video url?

Comment: You found any solution ?